# Android Sqlite: How to get the SQLite rowId from a Listview?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, rowid

I am creating a user selected favorites list by flagging items in the SQLite database table that populates a ListView. These flagged items will then populate the favorites ListView. To do this properly, I need to get the rowId  in the SQLite database table that the ListView is populated from so I can add the flag. How do I get the rowId?

Here's my current code:

OnItemClickListener:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int 
position, long id) {

            String selected = (String) 
mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            mItemTextView = findViewById(R.id.itemWords);
            mItemNumberTextView = findViewById(R.id.itemNumber);
            mId = id;

            mBookCopied = 
mItemHeaderNameTextView.getText().toString();
            mItemCategoryNumberCopied = Integer.toString(mCategorySelected + 1);
            mItemNumberCopied = 
mItemNumberTextView.getText().toString();
            mPosition = position + 1;
            mCopiedItemListItem = mItemCopied + " " + 
mCategoryNumberCopied + ":" + mPosition + "\n\n" + selected;

            showMenu(view);
        }
    });
```

ItemAdapter:

```
class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resource1, List<String> items) {
        super(context, resource1, items);
        mContext = context;
        mResource1 = resource1;
        mItems= items;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItem = convertView;
        int pos = position + 1;

        if (listItem == null) {
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mResource1, parent, false);
        }
        mItemNumberTextView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.itemNumber);
        mItemumberTextView.setText(String.valueOf(pos) + " ");

        mItemTextView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.itemWords);
        mItemTextView.setText(mItems.get(position));

        }

        return listItem;
    }
}
```

I have tried using the "long id" section of the onItemClickListener but that is just returning the position in the ListView. I need the actual rowId from the database table.

What am I missing here? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either

- use a CursorAdapater (then **long id** would then be the **ID** noting that the id column MUST be called **_id** (`BaseColumns._ID`), you can have a column that aliases **rowid** e.g. `rowid AS _id`).

  - e.g.  instead of `class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter....` use `class ItemAdapter extends CursorAdapter`
- use a source that includes the id NOT data extracted as `ArrayList<String>` but `ArrayList<suitable_object_with_id>` and access this via the getItem(position) and use the appropriate object's method to extract the id.
- build a complimentary array so that the position can access the **id**.

Comment: Thanks MikeT, I am going to try this and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Mike, I appreciate what you wrote. I am still having a lot of trouble with this. Can you possible provide some examples?

Comment: MikeT, I used the CursorAdapter and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help.